# Exercício com Matriz Indefinida de Strings

Tags: matriz

Estou tentando fazer um exercício onde o usuário por meio de uma sequencia aleatória decide o tamanho do Tabuleiro(Matriz) e como estarão organizado os valores. Por se tratar de um jogo onde a 3 Robôs(Reconhecidos na matriz pelas Iniciais) e eles devem chegar a um portal.

Minha duvida é como encontrar essas `Strings` A,B,C dentro da matriz e quando o usuário der um comando para movimentação dos robôs, eu conseguir alterar na matriz apenas aqueles valores, segue aqui a estrutura principal do Código:

```
main()
{
    system("color 0B");
    int lin, col, i,j;
    printf("Qual sera o tamanho do tabuleiro MxN:");
    scanf("%i",&lin);
    col = lin;
    char m[lin][col];
    system("Cls");
    printf("Neste Jogo voce decide como sera o tabuleiro!!\n");
    printf("Nele deve haver as inciais dos 3 robos\n");
    printf("Os # serao os obstaculos, X sera os portais e '.' sao casas 
    vazias.\n");
    printf("Faca uma sequencia com esses digitos e bom jogo");

    for(i=0; i<lin; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<col; j++)
        {
            printf("\nDigite a sequencia [%d][%d]: ",i,j);
            scanf("%s",&m[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nSeu tabuleiro e: \n");
    for(i=0; i<lin; i++)
    {
        printf("  %c", 'A'+i);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<lin; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("%c",'A'+i);
        for(j=0; j<col; j++)
        {
            printf("[%c]",m[i][j]);
        }
    }

}
```